# CRM 2011: Generic Error on Forward Email button "An error has occurred"

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Just came across an issue which causing lot of problems for the users. Whenever user click on forward email button, it takes the user to following error page. Can anyone one suggest me what could be the reason behind this issue.

I have tried to use IE developers toolkit but with no luck.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should check logs, impossible to know with this message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved.

Tried hard to find the problem in trace but could not found any thing specious. Finally I enabled the DevErrors in web.config and it displays the problem on screen. Problem is with a pre-validation plugin on email activity.

Answer (score 2):

To get detailed info about exception you should:
1. [Turn on tracing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907490/en).
2. Restart IIS.
3. Reproduce error.
4. Recheck trace folder, open trace file and get explanation of an error.